# Qt Won't Compile (10.5 Intel Mac)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to compile the latest version of Qt for the mac (from Gitorius). When I try to compile this (by doing ./configure and then make), I get the following error while running make:

```
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h: In function ‘T qvariant_cast(const QVariant&) [with T = QVariant]’:
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:592: error: ‘QVariant’ is not a member of ‘QMetaType’
make[2]: *** [.pch/debug-shared/QtCore_debug.gch/objective-c++] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
make: *** [sub-corelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you downloaded a stable version? Because you might accidentaly downloaded a beta/unstable version from Gitorious, which might not compile

Also, just download an appropiate stable version tarball from ftp.trolltech.com and compile it.

Comment: I'm so smart, I didn't even know that you could get the source that wasn't cutting-edge :)

Comment: @Maz Here is the source archiive ftp://ftp.qtsoftware.com/qt/source/